# Tracing Kernel Driver code in embedded linux development

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I am doing some embedded Linux development and am trying to implement a new instance of an EMIF interface. The Linux kernel already has an EMIF driver installed in it and uses it to read and write from NAND memory. The EMIF interface has 4 separate chip select lines and I would like to add a second device onto the EMIF bus using chip select 2.

1. How do I go about instantiating this device and reading and writing to it. (Device Tree addition?)
2. I have been trying to trace the Driver code from the Kernel source but am very new to driver development, what are the function calls that the kernel executes from the driver and where in the source do they occur? I believe I have found the source files for the driver since the have the same name as the `compatible = "ti,davinci-nand"` line in the device tree. Am I correct in assuming the driver source file would be called `davinci_nand.c` and located at `{linux source}/drivers/mtd/nand`

EDIT:

With some new information and a look at the device tree I posted this question which might be useful to anyone coming accross this thread.

[Deciphering Device Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839226/deciphering-device-tree)

Comment: About **Q1** - Identify if there exist nodes that describe the current device on the EMIF bus. If such nodes(and properties) exist, then they need to be duplicated and modified accordingly in the device-tree source for the new device that you plan to interface using the EMIF bus.

Comment: About **Q2** - You are on the right path. The file [**`davinci_nand.c`**](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/mtd/nand/davinci_nand.c#L526) is the correct file as it registers the same compatible string that you found in the device-tree source. Generally always search for the compatible string within the kernel source to locate the relevant driver. For example, `grep -rn "davinci-nand" kernel-src/drivers/` lists the source file of the driver that identifies itself by the name "`davinci-nand`".