# Deciphering Device Tree

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-tree

Here is an excerpt I pulled from a device tree on my embedded Linux Kernel. **This is how I understand it now:**

1) The `aemif` interface is located at physical address `0x30000000`

2) The `aemif` driver is located in a file called davinci_aemif.c and it uses a clock called `aemif`

3) The `aemif` has 2 devices on it, one being `cs2` and the other being `nand` (I don't think this assumption is correct)

**Now for the Questions:**

1) What is the line `reg = <0x21000a00 0x100>;` doing? How can the `aemif` which is located at `0x30000000` have address space at `0x21000a00`?

2) Why is `cs2` defined `cs2@30000000` and not `cs2@1,0`

3) What is the line `reg = <0x2 0x0 0x8000000 0x6 0x0 0x100>;` doing?

4) Any explanation of how the signal lines (ta, rhold, rstrobe, etc.) are set up would be helpful.

```
aemif@30000000 {
        compatible = "ti,davinci-aemif";
        #address-cells = <0x2>;
        #size-cells = <0x1>;
        reg = <0x21000a00 0x100>;
        ranges = <0x2 0x0 0x30000000 0x8000000 0x3 0x0 0x34000000 0x4000000 0x4 0x0 0x38000000 0x4000000 0x5 0x0 0x3c000000 0x4000000 0x6 0x0 0x21000a00 0x100>;
        clocks = <0x11>;
        clock-names = "aemif";

        cs2@30000000 {
            compatible = "ti,davinci-cs";
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x1>;
            ti,davinci-cs-ta = <0xc>;
            ti,davinci-cs-rhold = <0x6>;
            ti,davinci-cs-rstrobe = <0x17>;
            ti,davinci-cs-rsetup = <0x9>;
            ti,davinci-cs-whold = <0x8>;
            ti,davinci-cs-wstrobe = <0x17>;
            ti,davinci-cs-wsetup = <0x8>;
        };

        nand@2,0 {
            compatible = "ti,davinci-nand";
            reg = <0x2 0x0 0x8000000 0x6 0x0 0x100>;
            #address-cells = <0x1>;
            #size-cells = <0x1>;
            ti,davinci-chipselect = <0x0>;
            ti,davinci-mask-ale = <0x2000>;
            ti,davinci-mask-cle = <0x4000>;
            ti,davinci-mask-chipsel = <0x0>;
            ti,davinci-ecc-mode = "hw";
            ti,davinci-ecc-bits = <0x4>;
            ti,davinci-nand-use-bbt;
            ti,davinci-no-subpage-write;
            clocks = <0x11>;
            clock-names = "aemif";

            partition@0 {
                label = "u-boot";
                reg = <0x0 0x100000>;
                read-only;
            };

            partition@100000 {
                label = "params";
                reg = <0x100000 0x80000>;
                read-only;
            };

            partition@180000 {
                label = "ubifs";
                reg = <0x180000 0x1fe80000>;
            };
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Your device tree is obviously wrong.

1/ `reg = <0x21000a00 0x100>;` is informing that aemif is actually located at `0x21000a00` and has 32 registers (0x100/4) so the unit-address must be `0x21000a00`: `aemif@21000a00`

2/ again, the unit-address must match the reg property, you have no reg property in cs2..

3/ `reg = <0x2 0x0 0x8000000 0x6 0x0 0x100>;` reg refers to the ranges property of the node parent. Here, it can be interpreted as:
 - from range 0x2, at offset 0x0 (that would be 0x30000000), size 0x8000000
 - from range 0x6, offset 0x0, size 0x100

4/ you'll have to look a the driver having the "ti,davinci-cs" compatible string, I can't help as it is not mainlined.